# iphone program not running on device

Tags: ios, xcode

I have developed application for devices ios 4.2.1 and registered my devices on provisioning portal. Initially I used my own phone 4 to download and install the app, it worked and I can test it on this device. I added another test device on provisioning portal this time it is iphone 3g 4.2.1. It has been added to portal but I cannot run the application on the device, there are no error it said successfully compiled. 
When I went to Window ->Organizer I see Applications: No developed applications I don't see the button for Use this device for development. All my provisioning profiles and certificates are installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest SDK, there is a small issue regarding the architecture. Select your target and in the build settings replace the standard(armv7) with standard(armv6) and it should install and run correctly in 3gs devices and older.

Comment: In case you are not sure how to change to armv6, just doble click that setting and a pop up will appear, click on the + button in the popup and it will show you a window where you must write armv6. Once accepted, that option will be added to the available options and now you just need to select it as your actual configuration.

Comment: @Flink is totally right, this will solve your problems with devices under 3Gs and AFAIK it doesn't affect anything on devices running armv7 but I could be wrong about that.